# IPC using CORBA with C++ and Java

Tags: java, c++, corba, inter-process-communicat

I am decided to use CORBA to communicate between a C++ service and a java service. I want to know that is it possible using CORBA to inter call C++ library  and java library like we call a dll in an application. It will be very helpful if anyone help me to take a good decision!

Comment: Yes CORBA can communicate to C++ service and JAVA service. Refer documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/corba/index.html

Comment: Is CORBA can call a external library like DLL or JAR?

Comment: It is like calling a C++ method, would recommend you to read some more about CORBA on the web and try out a few things. See for example http://www.orbzone.org CORBA in general and http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt for TAO as C++ ORB

Answer (score 0):

(Seems some confusion in my previous answer.  I think it is better that I give another answer which state clearer my point)

CORBA is for interactions between "remote" components.  Although I used the term "Remote" here, it doesn't mean that components needs to be located in remote machine.  They can be in the same machine, or even same process.

The answer mostly depends on your aim:

If you are writing new libraries/components in C++ and Java, and you want to use them in the same application and have components in both language able to interact with each other, then yes, CORBA can help you in certain extend. However CORBA is helping you in the component communication part.  You still need to use JNI (or other similar solutions) to invoke/startup your C++/Java component in your Java/C++ application.  CORBA is not going to help you on this.  You may want to do extra POC to see if having two ORBs in same application (one for C++, one for Java) is going to cause you any problem.

If you are talking about: you already have some existing libraries which is written in Java and C++ (of course, not in CORBA-awared manner), and you are looking for way to make use of these library in your new application (in Java/C++).  Then no, CORBA cannot help you much on this.  Of course you can still write a extra layer which expose your components in CORBA, and make use of them, but making use of CORBA here is not going to make "calling C++ library or Java library" anything easier.

However, imho, neither case above seems to be a strong reason to make use of CORBA.  If you are just looking for interoperability of Java and C++ libraries, [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/), or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) maybe something you want to look into.